# Использование svg в android приложении

Tags: android, изображения, svg, icon

Как использовать svg иконки в приложении без деформации самой иконки?
Сначала делал все по этому [мини гайду](https://habrahabr.ru/post/265601/), но там кружки деформировались как пинг-понговые шарики при надавливании. Затем решил [гугловский](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html) вариант использовать: но элементы картинки съезжают (рис.) .
Гуглил другие варианты - результаты те же.
[image: Палочка]

**UPD:**
Проблема была в самом svg файле. Изначально работал с Inkscape, а теперь с Illustrator и все хорошо :D Не знаю, как это работает

Comment: видимо какие то ошибки при создании этого векторного изображения, что оно не может корректно конвертироваться.